# how to get the number on months between two dates in sql server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, datediff

I have a column in my sql server 2005 table that should hold the number of months an employee has been in service.

Since I also have the date the employee was engaged, I want the "months_In_Service" column to be a computed column.

Now if I use `DATEDIFF(month,[DateEngaged],GETDATE())` as the formula for the months in service computed column, the results are correct some times and other times incorrect.

What would be the better reliable way to get the number of months between the DateEngaged value and the current date? Which formula should i use in my computed column?

Comment: Could you provide some examples of what you mean when you say that sometimes they are correct and sometimes they are not.

Comment: Could you please retag this (edit) and set sql-server-2005 (or even just sql-server)?  Note the dashes.  There are users here who ignore SQL Server questions (not their expertise) but are interested in SQL questions.

Comment: DateEngaged = '12/20/2009"
CurrentDate = '1/13/2010"

That gives me months in service as 1 using formular "datediff(month,[DateEngaged],getdate()+(1))"

It also gives years in service as 1 using formula "datediff(year,[DateEngaged],getdate()+(1))"

Comment: And what result are you expecting?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Something like (might need to swap the 1 and 0, untested)

```
datediff(month,[DateEngaged],getdate()) +
 CASE WHEN DATEPART(day, [DateEngaged]) < DATEPART(day, getdate()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

DATEDIFF measure month boundaries eg 00:00 time on 1st of each month, not day-of-month anniversaries

Edit: after seeing OP's comment, you have to subtract 1 if the start day > end day

```
DATEDIFF (month, DateEngaged, getdate()) -
 CASE
   WHEN DATEPART(day, DateEngaged) > DATEPART(day, getdate()) THEN 1 ELSE 0
 END
```

So for 20 Dec to 13 Jan, DATEDIFF gives 1 and then 20 > 13 so subtract 1 = zero months.

Comment: this seems to work correctly, am just going to test it more just in case.

Comment: Did you ever test what happens when the employee engaged on 31 October and the current date was 30 November?  This routine returns 0 months, but in fact, virtually every business requirement I can imagine would say that is a month.  Found this looking for a solution to that very problem.  Still looking......

Comment: Not a brilliant solution to what @Ron is explaining?

Answer (score 4):

Same approach as gbn, but with less keystrokes :-)

```
SELECT 
    DATEDIFF(MONTH, DateEngaged, GETDATE()) +
    CASE 
        WHEN DAY(DateEngaged) < DAY(GETDATE())
        THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
    END
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want something like:

```
(year(getdate())-year([DateEngaged]))*12+(month(getdate())-month([DateEngaged]))
```

Answer (score -2):

If You presume that month is meaning for 30 days You can also round vale

```
round((datediff(day,[DateEngaged],getdate()))/30.00,0)
```

Comment: i exactly want month to mean 30 days and year twelve months of 30 days (each!!).

Comment: This drifts further and further out as time goes on. After 6 years, the error is a whole month, guaranteed